# Local Persistent Volume for Cassandra Hosted in Kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

We are trying to deploy Cassandra within Kubernetes. Thinking of the storage and how to make it work its fastest at each datacenter, without the expense of implementing network attached storage at each data center, it would seem reasonable to make use of a Local Persistent Volume at each datacenter and leverage Cassandra to handle the cross-datacenter replication. 
Am I thinking about this problem correctly? Is there a better way to consider implementing Cassandra in each of our data centers to make our application run their fastest by connecting to a more local data center?

Comment: Each node in Cassandra should have it's own local disk. You can read more about the issues with shared storage in Cassandra here: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/impact-of-shared-storage-on-apache-cassandra

Comment: That was my thinking as well.

Comment: We have very much the same issue at the moment: Trying to deploy Kubernetes with dynamic allocation of local storage. Afaik it's just not possible at this moment (Kubernetes is still very young). To use local storage I think you have to set up one pod at a time but please investigate this because I'm not 100 % sure.

Comment: Simon: I am looking at the Local Persistent Volumes for Kubernetes Goes Beta documentation to try and make this work:

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/

Comment: Oh so they are releasing this feature now, very cool! That should be what you're looking for then. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I have been able to successfully deploy cassandra in kubernetes using local storage. Wondering if a blog post would be valuable?

Comment: That would be awesome if you have time to do that. I'm sure the Cassandra user list will be interested as well. If you have less time you can always share an example on github. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @Simon your suggestion made me put together my first github repo. I've posted the steps and config files:

https://github.com/HuntJason/kubernetes/tree/master/cassandra-local-persistent-volumes

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thank you so much! I will definitely take a look at this. You should consider making a post in the Cassandra user list (https://cassandra.apache.org/community) to share with more people. Good work.

Comment: I have continued working on this. I have now been able to successfully get a Cassandra Ring backed on Local Persistent Storage installed in my k8s cluster. I have updated my sample in my github repo: 
https://github.com/HuntJason/kubernetes/tree/master/cassandra-ring-local-persistent-volumes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Simon Fontana Oscarsson is right.

I just want to add a bit more details about that feature for people who will find that question, because it is a common case.

1. Local Persistent Volumes are available only from 1.7 in alpha stage and from 1.10 in beta.
2. It requires pre-configured LVM on nodes, and it should be done before you will use it.
3. Here you may find examples of configuration [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/local-volume/examples).